# What is it called when someone addresses you by addressing their dog?

Tags: adjectives, terminology

A friend said something to their dog and it was meant for me. I told her that I am pretty sure that is passive aggressive, but don't think I am correct.

What is this called?

I attempted wording it several different ways, but continually received links that were not applicable.

Comment: That looks like using someone as a mouthpiece.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example, please? Was it something like "We don't like people wearing blue, do we, Fido"? Also, *what* did you look up which was not applicable? (Just so others don't suggest the same things, or can explain why something *is* applicable.)

Comment: It might be passive aggressive but it would depend what was said. If it was "she's beautiful, isn't she, Fido" that would be something else, a shy compliment maybe.

Comment: ...... Cynicism.